# SSRS performance Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report. The related procedure is taking less time to execute but the report loading is taking too much time. The procedure is taking less than 20 seconds and the number of records is around 5,00,000. Here number of records is high and it causing issue to load the report. So How can I improve report performance or Is there any other reporting tool other than SSRS which is support MSSQL and .Net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is execution time of the underlying query/proc, plus the calculation defined in the report plus the time to render the report. You can see the time takes for each part in ExecutionLogStorage table in [ReportingService] database on the server you installed your SSRS. Look for the columns [TimeDataRetrieval, [TimeProcessing] and [TimeRendering]. Then you can decide which part causes the slow. 500,000 may be too much to render in one page, you can set page size to show only very small portion of rows per page so the report will display quickly after you click run report, and you can click next page to show next portion (needs rendering).